# InstallShield MSI installer can not repair from Add Remove Programs, but works from installer

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I'm creating an MSI installer using Installshield Spring 2012. My installer works well except for one issue. If I delete a certain file in my install, and run repair from Add and Remove Program, the repair fails with error:

> Error 27506. Error executing SQL script SqlScript1.sql. Line 10. A file activation error occured. The physical file name 'SEICube.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation. (5105)

If I run the repair from within the installer, so, if I double click on my installer again, and choose repair, it works perfectly and I don't get any errors.

Any ideas?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log the installer in both scenarios and compare.  The main difference I can think of is that the Repair Button in ARP/PF  will run it in silent mode so the Install UI Sequence never runs.   The Modify button (or double clicking the MSI )  will start the UI sequence and then you select repair.   It may be a custom action is firing in the UI that makes it work.  In reality it should work silently so the custom action would be inappropriate.

Other possibly related thoughts are that MSI doesn't persist properties but InstallShield will in the case of connection string properties.   If you are using SSPI instead of database logins this can cause all kinds of problems depending on who is running the installer.

Another thought is becaue the database tier could be another server, the use of MDF / LDF files in an installer is not good.  The database should be fully scripted and created by the connection.  Also the scripts should be so robust that they support install, uninstall, reinstall, repair and upgrade from any previous schema to the current schema.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I'm not sure how to solve it though. I have a Custom Action type 51 that sets a property. It takes the value from [INSTALLDIR] and sets it into IS_DBFILES_PATH. It looks like when I run it from repair, IS_DBFILES_PATH is never set properly, I think because when the custom action runs, INSTALLDIR had not been added yet. When ran from the installer, the property gets set properly. This property is used in my script to find the MDF file. I'm not sure what I could do to have it work. At what point does INSTALLDIR gets set?

Comment: I just moved the custom action further down, that did the trick.

Comment: Directory properties get set by CostFinalize.  CostFinalize ran in your UI and was passed to the Execute.  When you ran silent it did't run yet so you had a race condition.